# R: how to divide period by integer in lubridate?

Tags: r, lubridate

**Lubridate** makes working with time easier, but sometimes it is hard for me to understand.

What I would like to do is to *divide a period by integer*. For example:

> If I run 5 km in 24m:45s what would I run 1 km in?

```r
# period gives me a time object
> as.period(ms("24:30"))
[1] "24M 30S"
```

But if I try to divide by 5 to get another object in minutes and seconds, it throws an error.

```r
> as.period(ms("24:30"))/5
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class “Period” object: periods must have integer values
```

What is the cause of this error and how to overcome this?

Many thanks:

Based on answer and comment below this is the **solution**:

```r
> as.period(as.duration(ms("24:30"))/5)
[1] "4M 54S"
```

It is necessary due to imprecise nature of period - "periods do not have fixed length".

Comment: Note that `as.period()` is superfluous. `ms("24:30")` is already of class `Period`

Comment: Thanks, very useful to know. Period comes in handy later if I need answer in min and sec.

Comment: @Aurèle, thanks, your help allows to understand the documentation better. Would you happen to know why Lubridate says "Intervals provide the only reliable way to convert between periods and durations"?

Comment: My mental model is that periods are somewhat abstract  (a "clock change") until provided a start time, at which point they "crystallize" into an interval, and from there an actual duration can be calculated. The unreliability of direct conversion stems from leap seconds and such. I would strive to avoid `Period` cmpletely here. I understand why you use ms(), because of the parsing convenience. `duration()` also has a parser, but unfortunately it doesn't work here (`duration("24:30")` fails while `duration("24M30S")` works). If you can manipulate the string formatting first, that's what I'd do.

Comment: That being said, I expect `as.duration(ms(...))` to always do the sensible thing here, so I wouldn't worry too much about it either :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend the `Duration` class over the `Period` class for your use case (running time).

> The exact length of each time unit in a period will depend on when it occurs. See Period and period(). [...]
>
> Because periods do not have a fixed length, they can not be accurately converted to and from Duration objects. Duration objects measure time spans in exact numbers of seconds

```
as.duration(ms("24:30")) / 5
#> [1] "294s (~4.9 minutes)"
```

Comment: Building on this, you could then use `as.period` to get the output back in minutes and seconds.

Comment: Thanks, this helps, especially with George's comment

Comment: `> as.period(as.duration(ms("24:30"))/5) 

[1] "4M 54S"`